# Device & ActiveResource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems, activeresource

I want to have 1 database for few projects and only one of them have direct connection to db, first of all I want to implement user authentication.
I should work over REST , without connecting to database. D you have any experience with devise gem working together with active resource. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a single-sign-on solution.  What you can do is setup one application to have a REST API, and enable single sign on for it which the others can utilize to connect to it.  [Try looking at this railscast about Single Sign On using OpenID.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/170-openid-with-authlogic)

Comment: I assume you mean `devise` not `device`.  Devise allows you to do authentication over http, but it isn't built with a corresponding client, so the nice helpers it provides won't work on the applications which don't store the user data out of the box.  Try taking a look at [this article](http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/12/16/multiple-applications-with-devise-omniauth-and-single-sign-on/).  Looks like this guy has figured out one way to use devise in an SSO setup.