# Devise Users in a different Database than rest of Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am currently starting out with writing a new application that should be installed multiple times on the same server (on a per-client basis).

The systems themselves should be seperated, the problem is that I require them all to use the same authentication.

Is there a way for devise to look at another database for authenticating users or should I maybe look into ActiveResource with a dedicated users service?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504530/device-activeresource ?

Comment: Unfortunately not the answer I am looking for: I am not looking for federated login using OpenID but rather a shared users database for devise. My Usernames *have* to be in my DB and I even need to import them from a old system. (I already need to change devise a bit to authenticate usernames instead of emails)

Comment: exactly I'm searching for such solution too

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having your user model use `database_authenticable`, you could write your own module (`shared_database_authenticable`) which looks up authentication info from the shared table. You can refer the `database_authenticable` code [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb)